# How do I find the maximum error that could result from early rounding?

Tags: rounding-error, significant-figures

I'm looking at code that does the following:

```
startRoundedValue = Round(startValue, 2); //rounds startValue to two decimal places
endRoundValue = Round(endValue, 2); //rounds endValue to two decimal places

intermediateRoundingResult = (endRoundValue - startRoundedValue) / startRoundedValue
```

`startValue` and `endValue` are decimal values (e.g. 123456.123456789012) with up 12 decimal places. Suppose I change the code to compute the result with rounding at the end:

```
unRoundedResult = (endValue - startValue)/startValue
roundingAtTheEndResult = Round(unRoundedResult, 2)
```

What would be the largest difference I could expect between `intermediateRoundingResult` and `roundingAtTheEndResult`?

We can ignore the case where startValue rounds to zero.

**Update**

For example, let's suppose  `startValue=0.05` and `endValue=0.014999999999`, I get `roundingAtTheEndResult =2.33` and `intermediateRoundingResult=4.00` for a difference of `1.67`.

If instead, `startValue=4002.0549` and `endValue=18.019112`, I get `roundingAtTheEndResult=221.10` and `intermediateRoundingResult=221.09` for a difference of `0.01`.

I'm trying to determine max difference that is possible for any arbitrary `startValue` and `endValue`

Comment: The answer depends very much on what kind of operations were done, and with what numbers.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - Thanks for your comment. `startValue` and `endValue` can be any decimal number. The operations are in the OP. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding your comment. Could you please explain a bit more?